# Modify NetCDF file to make dimension unlimited

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

Is it possible, with Python + netCDF4, to open an existing NetCDF file and change one of the dimensions from fixed size to an unlimited dimension, such that I can append data to it?

I found [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598485/how-to-convert-fixed-size-dimension-to-unlimited-in-a-netcdf-file), which lists several options for doing this with NCO/xarray, but I'm specifically looking for a method using the netCDF4 package.

Below is a minimal example which creates a NetCDF file with a fixed dimension (*this part, of course, does not exist in reality, otherwise I could simply create the file with an unlimited dimension...*), and then re-opens it in an attempt to modify the `time` dimension. The `netCDF4.Dimension time_dim` has a function/method `isunlimited()` to test whether the dimension is unlimited or not, but nothing like e.g. `make_unlimited()`, which I was hoping for.

```
import netCDF4 as nc4
import numpy as np

# Create dataset for testing
nc1 = nc4.Dataset('test.nc', 'w')
dim = nc1.createDimension('time', 10)
var = nc1.createVariable('time', 'f8', 'time')
var[:] = np.arange(10)
nc1.close()

# Read it back
nc2 = nc4.Dataset('test.nc', 'a')
time_dim = nc2.dimensions['time']

# ...
# (1) Make time_dim unlimited
# (2) Append some data
# ...

nc2.close()
```

Comment: I think you need to create a new unlimited time dimension and a variable based on this and copy all data over.

Comment: But then the dimension has a different name (unless you make a temporary copy of everything, remove the old dimensions/variables, create the unlimited dim with its old name and copy everything back, which would be a pain in the ....)

Comment: Well, you can rename a dimension with `nc2.renameDimension('time', 'tmp_time)` before making a new one named `time`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, didn't know that! I'll see what I can do with that

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
# rename the old dimension
data.renameDimension('time_dim', 'tmp_dim')
# create a new unlimited dimension with the old fixed size dimension's name
data.createDimension('time_dim', None)
# copy the data from the renamed dimension
time_dim[:] = tmp_dim[:]
# delete the temporary dimension
del data.dimensions['tmp_dim']
```